# Angular JS use NG-Hide with function

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide

I try to create an Angular JS function that is displaying or hiding a Div in case that a certain requirement is met.
I do have the problem now that the function is not properly called and both divs are either visible or not visible (In the test case div 1 should be shown and div 2 not).

```
testApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope','$http',
function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.checkValue = function(value){
    if(value >= 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    };
}]);
```

In the html file I try to hide the Divs using the following parameters

```
<div class="classa" ng-hide="requestsExisting({{profile.arrayA.length}})">
<div class="classb" ng-hide="requestsExisting({{profile.arrayB.length}})">
```

Is during the run time the `{{profile.parameterA.length}}`passed to the function or the actual value that is stored in this variables? (It's 1 for `arrayA` and 0 for `ArrayB`)

Comment: i think you just need requestsExisting(profile.arrayA.length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need the "{{" sign.
just do

```
<div class="classa" ng-hide="requestsExisting(profile.arrayA.length)">
<div class="classb" ng-hide="requestsExisting(profile.arrayB.length)">
```

the double curly brace is to put the value of the object in the html

> The double curly brace notation {{ }} to bind expressions to elements
>   is built-in Angular markup

Answer (score 1):

I think that it should work just with this code

```
<div class="classa" ng-hide="requestsExisting(profile.arrayA.length)">
<div class="classb" ng-hide="requestsExisting(profile.arrayB.length)">
```

I think that you don't need to use {{}} inside the ng-hide directive